# Add sub-elements to newly created elements in python elementtree

Tags: python, append, element, elementtree

I am trying to add the following subtree to an element 'Drugs' in an xml file using elementtree in Python based on the data in CSV file:

```
<Drug>
     <DrugID>1<DrugID>
     <Dose>40</Dose>
     <Unit>mg</Unit>
</Drug>
<Drug>
     <DrugID>3<DrugID>
     <Dose>1</Dose>
     <Unit>g</Unit>
</Drug>
```

The thing is once I have created the Drug element, how do I reference it to use the append function? `element.append()` as I understand it needs element to be a direct reference to the parent. If I use `.find()` when adding the second drug, I may instead get a reference to the first drug.

I am cycling through each line of CSV while doing this so that's why I'd rather add element by element rather than appending a subtree to the element Drugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`SubElement` factory](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents) to add new elements, it's much easier to use:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

# drugs is a reference to your <Drugs> element

for row in csvreader:
    drug = ET.SubElement(drugs, 'Drug')
    ET.SubElement(drug, 'DrugID').text = row[0]
    ET.SubElement(drug, 'Dose').text = row[1]
    ET.SubElement(drug, 'Unit').text = row[2]
```

where I assume that the columns 1 - 3 are the drug id, dose and unit, adjust as required for your CSV file.

Calling `SubElement()` creates the element, adds it to the parent and returns the newly created element for further processing.